Unstable WiFi connection on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
enter image description hereAfter I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04, the WiFi started to disconnect randomly. It shows activation of network connection failed for some seconds and then connects very poorly and then disconnects again. It is very unstable, but with ethernet cable it works perfect, please help me! I don't know what logs do you need and how to get them.

iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.


enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Familia beltran hernandez_2.4G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: ************  
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:23   Missed beacon:0





sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)





sudo lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3fd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam (Asus N-series)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:3402 IMC Networks Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


Log
SystemD
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Priority 6
Unit Unsucceeded
The unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.

Have the same problem and only a restart fixes it until after some time it crashes again.

In order to restart the iwlwifi driver without a complete system restart please see here how to achieve this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1522501/885300

Two things you can try, that helped in my case :

Edit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf, and change the value of wifi.powersave to 2 (should be 3 by default).
This first tweak disables the Power Management (/Power Savings) feature of the Wifi adapter. It has often been listed as a culprit in performance and disconnects.
In the NetworkManager gui (where you usually manage your Wifi or other network connections, graphically), delete any Wifi connection that your computer has remembered but you don't use. Ideally only keep the one you need right now.

It's a bit early for me to confirm that it doesn't happen at all anymore in my case, but it's been a few days and I haven't seen the disconnects again !
Hope this helps.

I tried but didn't work, it is still very unstable, how could I troubleshoot the problem?

I get this form the log   Log
SystemD
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Priority 6
Unit Unsucceeded
The unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.

I'm sorry I won't have the skills to assist further.

Changing wifi.powersave as described solved the problem for me. Wifi is stable now.
